# show div B on element A focus & hide element B on element B blur

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

sorry for simple question but I really didn't find a simple && functional example written with jquery for this..

my HTML code :

```
<a class="A"></a>
<div class="B">
    <!-- a form here -->
</div>
```

I need a piece of jquery code which does this for me :
" show div B on element A focus, and hide element B on element B blur "
by "element B blur" I mean focusing on any other elements of body except B

I wrote something for it but it doesn't work :

```
$(function () {
    $('.A').on('focus', function () {
        $('.B').show();
    }, function () {
        $('body').not('.B').on('click', function () {
            $('.B').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Any body can help me with this plz ? thanks ..

Comment: I somehow don't get how a `<div>` can get a focus.

Comment: hmm actually div works with focus as I test in my codes .. I'm not completely certain about this. by the way, no problem I can change DIV with input or anything else that works with focus function

Comment: Focus is for `<a>`'s and form elements. For a div, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Ok thanks, I edit my question, changing DIV with A. but I'm testing DIV and focus works with it, maybe new stuff in jquery 1.10 ..., can you help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. as you have said , when we focus on on A the click event of body is called...the way around for avoiding this is to check if the element is .B or its desendent, then don't hide().. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh92P/3) ..

```
$(function () {
   $('.A').on('click', function () {
      $('.B').show();
   });

  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
     if (!$('.A,.B').is(e.target) && $('.A,.B').has(e.target).length === 0) {
          $('.B').hide();
     }
  });

});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, because when we focus on .B element, we are clicking on  $('body').not('.B') elements at the same time, so the .B elements shows up for a moment and goes hidden again ..

Comment: then i guess you need to use some other events... it would be better if you can create a fiddle so to understand what actaully you need . i am bit consufsed

Comment: well.. as you have said , when we focus on on A the click event of body is called...the way around for avoiding this is to check if the element is .B or its desendent don't hide().. fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/Dh92P/3/  ..hope this helps...atleast this will get you started..

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I changed $('body') to $(document) and it works as I want. If you want, write an answer for me then I can accept it .. thanks again

Comment: welcome...glad it helped :) ..updated my answer.... edit it if it needs changes so it helps others.. happy coding